# What is the difference between the rate of rotation tensor and spin tensor?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, continuum-mechanics

In continuum mechanics the velocity gradient ***l*** is additively splitted into a symmetric ***d*** and skew-symmetric ***w*** part, where ***d*** is the rate of deformation tensor and ***w*** is called spin tensor.

From the polar decomposition of the deformation gradient ***F*** we have ***F = RU***, where ***R*** is a proper othogonal tensor and ***U*** is the right stretch tensor.

In many textbooks one can find the following connection between these tensor and their time rates, respectively:

$$w = \dot{R}R^T + \frac{1}{2} R(\dot{U}U^{-1} - U^{-1}\dot{U})R^T$$

My question is:

1) What is the physical interpretation of ***w***? Many textbooks say, it describes the rotation of a material element, but this is only true for a rigid body motion where ***U*** is zero and the formula reduces to the well known form of the angular velocity tensor of rigid body: $$w = \dot{R}R^T$$
Otherwise ***w*** contains also stretch/strain rate. Can someone tell please, how to interpret ***w*** and its terms. And whats the difference compared to the time rate of rotation $$\dot{R}$$ or $$\dot{R}R^T$$ which should describe the rotation rate rather than ***w*** in my opinion.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term involving $\mathbf{U}$ represents the spin of the stretch eigendirections. It is a purely mathematical quantity, moreover it cannot be measured as $\mathbf{U}$ is in the reference placement. This is probably why it is so hard to interpret.